# How do i find the coordinates of a resource?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game and I started by making some framework just for me to learn and test different things within it the game. In this game, I have a randomly generated tilemap with the resources dirt, grass, water, and coal. In the code, there are some other irrelevant resources but what I'm trying to do is find the coordinates of a specific resource in the game. What I plan on doing with this is say the resource is a wall and there is a wall below it and next to it the texture for the middle wall will turn into a corner piece. My issue is I don't know how to find the coordinates. Can someone please help me, I honestly am not sure what I'm doing but I'm trying to learn.
Heres my code:

```
import pygame, sys
import Sprites
import random

from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()


fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

cloudx = -200
cloudy = 0

infoObject = pygame.display.Info()

DIRT = 0
GRASS = 1
WATER = 2
COAL = 3
CLOUD = 4
WALL = 5

controls = {
    DIRT : 49,
    GRASS: 50,
    WATER: 51,
    COAL : 52,
    WALL : 53
}

infoObject = pygame.display.Info()

w = infoObject.current_w
h = infoObject.current_h

TILESIZE  = 40
MAPWIDTH  = 15
MAPHEIGHT = 15

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)

resources = [DIRT, GRASS, WATER, COAL]

textures =  {
            DIRT  : pygame.image.load('Sprites/Dirt.png'),
            GRASS : pygame.image.load('Sprites/tile130.png'),
            WATER : pygame.image.load('Sprites/Water.png'),
            COAL  : pygame.image.load('Sprites/Coal.png'),
            CLOUD : pygame.image.load('Sprites/Cloud.png'),
            WALL  : pygame.image.load('Sprites/Swall.png')
          }

playerPos = [0,0]

inventory = {
            DIRT   :  0,
            GRASS  :  0,
            WATER  :  0,
            COAL   :  0,
            WALL   :  10,
            }

tilemap = [[DIRT for w in range(MAPWIDTH)] for h in range(MAPHEIGHT)]



DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE,MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE + 50))

pygame.display.set_caption('M I N E C R A F T -- 2D')
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('Sprites/player.png'))

PLAYER = pygame.image.load('Sprites/Player.png').convert_alpha()

for rw in range(MAPHEIGHT):
    for cl in range(MAPWIDTH):
        randomNumber = random.randint(0,15)
        if randomNumber == 0:
            tile = COAL
        elif randomNumber == 1 or randomNumber == 2:
            tile = WATER
        elif randomNumber >= 3 and randomNumber <=7:
            tile = GRASS
        else:
            tile = DIRT

        tilemap[rw][cl] = tile

INVFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 18)

print(tilemap)

while True:

    currentTile = tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]]

    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BLACK)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
#        print(event)
        if event.type == QUIT:

            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:

            for key in controls:


                if (event.key == controls[key]):

                    if inventory[key] > 0:

                        inventory[key] -=1

                        inventory[currentTile] += 1

                        tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]] = key

            if(event.key == K_RIGHT) and playerPos[0] < MAPWIDTH - 1:
                playerPos[0]+=1

            elif(event.key == K_LEFT) and playerPos[0] > 0:
                playerPos[0]-=1

            elif(event.key == K_DOWN) and playerPos[1] < MAPHEIGHT - 1:
                playerPos[1]+=1

            elif(event.key == K_UP) and playerPos[1] > 0:
                playerPos[1]-=1

            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                currentTile = tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]]
                inventory[currentTile] += 1
                tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]] = DIRT

    for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
        for column in range(MAPWIDTH):
                DISPLAYSURF.blit(textures[tilemap[row][column]],(column*TILESIZE, row*TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
                DISPLAYSURF.blit(PLAYER,(playerPos[0]*TILESIZE,playerPos[1]*TILESIZE))


    DISPLAYSURF.blit(textures[CLOUD].convert_alpha(),(cloudx,cloudy))
    cloudx +=1

    if cloudx > MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE:
        cloudy = random.randint(0, MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE)
        cloudx = -200


    placePosition = 10
    for item in resources:
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(textures[item],(placePosition, MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE+10))
        placePosition+=50
        textObj = INVFONT.render(str(inventory[item]), True, WHITE, BLACK)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(textObj,(placePosition, MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE+20))
        placePosition += 50

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(24)

    for x in range(MAPWIDTH):
        for y in range(MAPHEIGHT):
            if tilemap[x][y] == WALL:
                pos = tilemap[x][y]
                if tilemap[pos[1]][pos[0]-1] == WALL:
                    print('I DID IT')

    pygame.display.update()
```

Edit: My current code has been updated, the added part is at the very end

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the coordinates of a specific tile, then it's going to take some work. Namely, your program will have to search through every tile and compare it to see if it's a `WALL` tile.
i.e.

```
for x in range(MAPWIDTH):
    for y in range(MAPHEIGHT):
        if tilemap[y][x] == WALL:
            # Do something here...
```

However, this is *extremely* inefficient. Though it may not be a problem when your map is only 15 by 15, it will start to eat up your performance if you expand the map.

It might be wiser to only check the area that's being shown on the screen. After all, you're only trying to work out how the tile should be *displayed* - it doesn't matter otherwise.

```
for x in range(30): # Replace with whatever number of tiles is displayed horizontally on the screen, times two
    for y in range(30): # Do the same here
        if tilemap[y][x] == WALL:
            # Do something here
```

Just a quick note, though - if this is only for display, a far better solution for this is to define multiple `WALL` tiles. You could do this by just making constants like `WALL_UPPER_RIGHT`, but it would be a much better idea to make it in the form of a list.

```
WALL_TILES = [[5, 6, 7],
              [8, 9, 10],
              [11, 12, 13]]
# WALL_TILES is a 2D list in the format:
# upper left    upper middle    upper right
# middle left  middle middle   middle right
# lower left    lower middle    lower right
```

Then, you could just address something like `WALL_UPPER_RIGHT` with `WALL_TILES[0][2]`. When you have your multiple wall tiles, you can just change the type of tile whenever it or a tile next to it gets changed.

**ADDED:**

To check if surrounding tiles are also wall tiles, you could check the tiles whose x-position and y-position are both within 1 of the center tile. For example, you could check `tilemap[pos[1]][pos[0]-1]`.

Comment: @user123 thankyou very much. You have been a huge help

Comment: could you steer me in the right direction as how to check if there is a wall tyle next to it? Also i wasnt sure what your last list example meant. I am new to this

Comment: i added that line and tried to name pos as    pos = WALL[x][y] but that doesnt seem to work, how would i go about doing that. Also, thankyou for your time, i very much appreciate it

Comment: Ah. `pos` is supposed to denote the position of the wall tile. I didn't add it in the post, but remember to add code to check and make sure you aren't trying to check any tiles that aren't on the map, like the tile to the left of the leftmost tile.

Comment: i got that but im not sure how to denote the position.

Comment: can you please help?